# update $wpdb one query

Tags: query, wpdb

Is there a way to change mysql directly in wordpress just 1 operation without needing 2 operations: query and update?

I am facing problem of multiple concurrent transactions impacting point_user

I found the solution here, however I don't know how to implement it on wordpress

```
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60681/transaction-basics-what-is-the-result-of-2-transactions-running-concurrently
```

Demo query sql

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = meta_value - 1  WHERE post_id = 9999 AND meta_key = 'point_user'
```

Is there a way to update it like this?

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = meta_value - 1  WHERE post_id= 9999 AND meta_key = 'point_user'"));
```

I'm stuck, many thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `$wpdb->prepare`.

```
$wpdb->query("UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = meta_value - 1  WHERE post_id= 9999 AND meta_key = 'point_user'");
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).